# Ubuntu 22.04 bash one-liner to identify device backing a LUKS volume?

Tags: mount, mountpoint

I have a standard ubuntu encrypted lvm setup. `/dev/sda3` is encrypted w/ LUKS. Inside that LUKS container is an LVM ( at `/dev/mapper/dm_crypt-0` )and inside that LVM is a filesystem mounted from `/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv` to `/`

How can I convert the known mount point of `/` to `/dev/sda3` in a one-liner in bash, preferably without root? I would be happy to install an separate utility if it could accomplish this.

I have figured out `df|tail -n +2|cut -f 1 -d` to get me `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` but how do I get `/dev/sda3` from that?

Comment: You have to work in reverse.  Except that LVM doesn't behave the same as standard partitioning.  Start by looking at the volume - `sudo lvs`.  That will get you the volume group.  From that, look at the volume group - `sudo vgs`.  That will get you the physical volumes backing the volume group.  From that look at `sudo pvs` which lists the physical volumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a simpler and more efficient way to do this, but I was able to achieve what you want using `lsblk`, `grep`, and `awk` without needing root access.

### tl;dr

```
pkname=$(lsblk -o MOUNTPOINT,PKNAME | grep "^/"[^[:alnum:]] | awk '{ print $2 }');pkname=$(lsblk -o PATH,PKNAME,KNAME | grep $pkname | awk -v val="$pkname" '$3 == val { print $2 }');lsblk -o PATH,KNAME | grep $pkname | awk '{ print $1 }';unset pkname
```

---

Let's break it down and use a test VM as an example, Ubuntu 22.04.3 Server. Start with the output of `lsblk`. As you can see, all the info you want is there. It shows the mountpoint and path up the tree to `/dev/sda3`. The challenge is how to parse this output to get the path `/dev/sda3` from the mountpoint, `/`.

```
$ lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                         7:0    0  63.4M  1 loop  /snap/core20/1974
loop1                         7:1    0 111.9M  1 loop  /snap/lxd/24322
loop2                         7:2    0  53.3M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/19457
sda                           8:0    0    25G  0 disk  
├─sda1                        8:1    0     1M  0 part  
├─sda2                        8:2    0     2G  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                        8:3    0    23G  0 part  
  └─dm_crypt-0              253:0    0    23G  0 crypt 
    └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:1    0    23G  0 lvm   /
sr0                          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Fortunately, `lsblk` has an `-o` option that allows you to supply a list of columns to print. This displays additional info that can be parsed with `grep` and `awk`. Look at `lsblk --help` for a complete list. To start, I chose `MOUNTPOINT` and `PKNAME`, but I'll also be using `PATH` and `KNAME` later.

```
$ lsblk --help
--snip--
 KNAME  internal kernel device name
 PATH  path to the device node
--snip--
 MOUNTPOINT  where the device is mounted
--snip--
 PKNAME  internal parent kernel device name
--snip--
```

**1. Find the `PKNAME` for mountpoint: `/`**

The following line prints the `MOUNTPOINT` and `PKNAME` associated with `/` mountpoint:

```
$ lsblk -o MOUNTPOINT,PKNAME | grep "^/"[^[:alnum:]]
/                 dm-0
```

Use `awk` to print and assign the 2nd column, `PKNAME`, to a variable:

```
$ pkname=$(lsblk -o MOUNTPOINT,PKNAME | grep "^/"[^[:alnum:]] | awk '{ print $2 }')
$ echo $pkname
dm-0
```

**2. Find the `PKNAME` for the previous `PKNAME`**

Use `lsblk` again, this time with `PATH`, `PKNAME`, and `KNAME` as columns. Use `grep` to find lines containing the value of `$pkname`:

```
$ lsblk -o PATH,PKNAME,KNAME | grep $pkname
/dev/mapper/dm_crypt-0            sda3   dm-0
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv dm-0   dm-1
```

This results in two matches, but we only want a match where `$pkname` matches the 3rd column, which is `KNAME`. The 2nd column, `PKNAME`, has to be included, because that's the next value needed.

Use `awk` again to get that value, and re-assign it to your variable:

```
$ pkname=$(lsblk -o PATH,PKNAME,KNAME | grep $pkname | awk -v val="$pkname" '$3 == val { print $2 }')
$ echo $pkname
sda3
```

**3. Find the `PATH` for the previous `PKNAME`**

Use `lsblk` to display `PATH` and `KNAME` columns, `grep` to find the matching line, and `awk` to print the first column, `PATH`:

```
$ lsblk -o PATH,KNAME | grep $pkname | awk '{ print $1 }'
/dev/sda3
```

---

Finally, combine all of the commands together, separated by semi-colons. To be complete, tack on an `unset` at the end to clear the variable, `$pkname`. There's your one-liner without needing root access.

```
$ pkname=$(lsblk -o MOUNTPOINT,PKNAME | grep "^/"[^[:alnum:]] | awk '{ print $2 }');pkname=$(lsblk -o PATH,PKNAME,KNAME | grep $pkname | awk -v val="$pkname" '$3 == val { print $2 }');lsblk -o PATH,KNAME | grep $pkname | awk '{ print $1 }';unset pkname
/dev/sda3
```

Comment: Thank you this is an awesome answer!

Comment: @Mr.T You're welcome. :)